# Is there a way to make Stackdriver Alert more specific?

Tags: policy, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring

I am creating monitoring alerts on several metrics.

I am putting 2 examples below:
1) dataflow job failed
2) firewall rule changed or new rule inserted

Creating log-based metric and alert from it is fine. But it is very generic. How do I pin point to specific detail like this dataflow job (job name) failed or dataflow job created by this user failed?
Same for the firewall rule, how do I know which rule out of all is updated?

How can I include job name or pin point resource in question in the alert message itself?

For the example I provided, configuration are below -

Firewall update metric is created using following filter:

```
resource.type="gce_firewall_rule" AND jsonPayload.event_subtype="compute.firewalls.patch" OR jsonPayload.event_subtype="compute.firewalls.insert"
```

For dataflow failed job there is metric available in metric explorer - is_failed

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that is done by default, according to [this](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/using-stackdriver-monitoring#create_alerts_for_cloud_dataflow_metrics), when an alert is triggered by a dataflow job, the alert details contains which dataflow job triggered it.

Is this what you were looking?

Comment: I wish it was case by default. I am not able to share snippet of the email alert I receive due to security policy of the enterprise. Alerting does not pinpoint any job for the metric is_failed for the dataflow_job resource type. In the link you provided,it is different metric. Thanks for the answer by the way.